# Why does IntelliJ suggest to use the elvis operator in a test and skip the assertions?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have this test case in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-212.5457.46, built on October 12, 2021:

```kotlin
@Test
fun mcve() {
    val exception = assertThrows<IllegalArgumentException> {
        throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("just for texting")
    }
    val msg = exception.message!!
    assertTrue(msg.contains("testing"), "Should have 'testing' but got '$msg'")
}
```

I use `msg` because in real life the expression is longer and I want to keep my assertions shorter.

[image: IntelliJ screenshot]

IntelliJ now suggests to `Replace '!!' with '?: return'` and make the line look like this:

```kotlin
val msg = exception.message ?: return
```

This would mean that if there was no message, the test would pass, but it should only pass if there was a message and it contained "testing".

Why does IntelliJ suggest this, when it's different from the original code's behavior? Am I missing something about Kotlin here?

Comment: IntelliJ should not suggest `exception.message ?: return` in this context. Can you share a screenshot of that suggestion? I did not get that suggestion.

Comment: @ocos I added a screenshot. This is in a regular `src/kotlin/test/` folder in a Gradle project, by the way. The lines that are cut off are the `package...` and more JUnit 5 imports.

Comment: There may be an internal caching/indexing problem of IntelliJ Inspection plugin or another static code analyser plugin may interfere: sonarlint, detekt... The answers are oriented to how to write good unit tests but I think this warning is inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does seem wrong in the context of a test, it should be more explicit about why it says that. But there is one thing to consider. If your `!!` expression is wrong, and the exception message is actually null, all you will get is an NPE, not a false assert.

To clarify, `Exception.message` is nullable, that is how the `Exception` class is defined. You do know that the `message` is initialised to "just for texting", but the compiler can't know that for sure, something else in another thread might have changed it for example, or the exception that it received might not have a message at all.

That means that from the point of view of the compiler `msg.contains("testing")` will never run if your assumption is wrong, so there is no point in going forward, so might as well return out of it.

If you want to check it properly, then you should either add another assertion for `msg` not null,

```
val msg = exception.message
assertTrue(msg != null, "whatever message")
assertTrue(msg.contains("testing"), "Should have 'testing' but got '$msg'")
```

Or leave `msg` as `String?` and take advantage of `?` in combination with `== true` and have a single assertion.

```
val msg = exception.message
assertTrue(msg?.contains("testing") == true, "Should have 'testing' but got '$msg'")
```

Comment: I want the test to fail noisily, and I thought with the `!!` I wouldn't have to manually assert that I do have a `msg`. Maybe the `msg?.contains` is the best way here.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for how to correctly handle the null.

```
@Test
fun mcve() {
    val exception = assertThrows<IllegalArgumentException> {
        throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("just for texting")
    }
    val msg = exception.message ?: fail("exception did not have a message")
    assertTrue(msg.contains("testing"), "Should have 'testing' but got '$msg'")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if whatever exception *is* thrown has a *null* message? (I know in this code that can't happen, but the `assertThrows` method can't provide that guarantee to the compiler.) Using `!!` will crash the test in that case. Since you're not trying to handle that potential *null* in your code, it looks like the IDE is suggesting you ignore it in a safer way.

You might want to do this instead:

```
// leave it as a nullable type
val msg = exception.message
// account for the possible null (condition can evaluate to true, false or null)
assertTrue(msg?.contains("testing") == true, "Should have 'testing' but got '$msg'")
```

or just suppress the warning if you know the exception is going to have a non-null `message` (but if you know exactly what's going to be thrown, why do you need to test it?)

Comment: I do want the test to fail noisily if there is no message. It's not that I am ignoring this condition, I want to assert on `msg`, and if it's `null`, the test should fail. But with the elvis operator, the test won't assert anything and pass if `msg` is `null`, where it should fail. That's where I am confused as to why IntelliJ suggests this change. The real example doesn't throw in the test case, this is just for a nice and small mcve.

Comment: @Robert If `message` is *null* then the test won't *fail*, it'll *crash* - it's a broken test. That's your current behaviour, in that situation you won't do any assertions on `msg` anyway because the test has fallen over. So I see this more as IntelliJ highlighting this issue and saying "do you just not want to handle the possibility of a null?" (which you're not at the moment, so it's consistent!) and you can accept that suggestion and explicitly exit the test if it's *null*, or you can go "oh right kinda need to handle that too as part of my assertions" and fix it

Comment: Personally, I don't care if a test fails or crashes, I want everything to pass. I feel this is taking us in the wrong direction, though: why does IntelliJ suggest a code change that changes the meaning of the code from failing noisily to silently ignoring the null value?

Comment: @Robert like I said, it seems consistent to me. A failed test and code that crashes absolutely aren't the same thing, even if they both get your attention. The linter's just suggesting a change that tests exactly the same things your current test does, except the code isn't broken - it can't know that you *want* it to crash. And honestly, it's right - crashing is bad, it makes the intent of the test less clear, it's not how you're meant to use a testing framework and it just causes problems. But if it's really what you want to do, you can just suppress the warning! Wouldn't recommend it though